# Creating Let's Encrypt certificate without root access and different port

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot, acme

I try to create a certificate without root access because my web apps will be creating/renewing certs automatically. I found acme.sh, i was able to create a certficate with non-root user over 80.port. However my application is working port 8000. Is there any way verify different port instead of 80. port ?

```
/home/webapp/.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue --webroot ~/public_html -d mydomain.com --staging --debug
```

also tried `--httpport` argument, not worked

```
/home/webapp/.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue --webroot ~/public_html --httpport 3000 -d mydomain.com --staging --debug
```

By the way, I can't use DNS-01 challenge verification.